# Pig Filter on Positional Variable

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to filter on a positional variable.

```
X = FILTER C BY($14 matches '.*USD.*');
STORE X into '$output' using PigStorage(',');
```

Above statement doesn't work, but if I try to just output $14

```
E = FOREACH C GENERATE FLATTEN($14);
STORE C into '$output' using PigStorage(',');
```

It works fine

Sample data:

```
304a285281be,1383027928890968764,receiver,10C,655362,C2,USD811289,1,0,0,ebay_checkout,cc,cc,USD2659,USD120
304a285281be,1383027928890968764,receiver,10C,655362,C2,USD811289,1,0,0,ebay_checkout,cc,cc,USD2659,USD0
304a285281be,1383027928890968764,receiver,10C,655362,C2,USD811289,1,0,0,ebay_checkout,cc,cc,USD2659,GBP0
```

Sample output

```
304a285281be,1383027928890968764,receiver,10C,655362,C2,USD811289,1,0,0,ebay_checkout,cc,cc,USD2659,USD0
304a285281be,1383027928890968764,receiver,10C,655362,C2,USD811289,1,0,0,ebay_checkout,cc,cc,USD2659,GBP0
```

Comment: My problem was chararray to string conversion added to_str($14) and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a space between 'BY' and '('

```
    X = FILTER C BY (FLATTEN($14) matches '.*USD.*');
    STORE X into '$output' using PigStorage(',');
```

Comment: It still doesnt work for me, Itried with and without FLATTEN

Comment: @FarheenNoorie Post sample data and expected output and your entire script

Answer (score 0):

This is Working for me with your input :

```
A = LOAD 'StackFile.txt'  using PigStorage(',');
B = FILTER A BY ($14 matches '.*USD.*');
DUMP B;
```

> Blockquote
>
> 304a285281be,1383027928890968764,receiver,10C,655362,C2,USD811289,1,0,0,ebay_checkout,cc,cc,USD2659,USD120
>   304a285281be,1383027928890968764,receiver,10C,655362,C2,USD811289,1,0,0,ebay_checkout,cc,cc,USD2659,USD0